# If a covering map $p : Y \to X$ maps $V \subset Y$ homeomorphically onto an open $U \subset X$, must $V$ be open in $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Let $p : Y \to X$ be a covering projection and let $V \subset Y$ be a subset which is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto an open $U \subset X$.

Question: Is $V$ necessarily open in $Y$?

In the special case when $X$ is locally connected the answer is "yes", but I do not know what happens when $X$ is not locally connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yes" in the locally connected case.

Let $y \in V$. There exists a connected open neigborhood $U' \subset U$ of $p(y)$ in $X$ which is evenly covered. Let $\{V'_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a decomposition of $p^{-1}(U')$ into open subsets of $Y$ such the restrictions $p_\alpha : V'_\alpha \to U'$ of $p$ are homeomorphisms. Let $W = V \cap p^{-1}(U')$ and $W_\alpha = V \cap V'_\alpha$. There exists a unique $\alpha(y) \in A$ such that $y \in W_{\alpha(y)}$. The sets $W_\alpha$ form a cover of $W$ by pairwise disjoint open subsets  of $W$. The restriction $p_W : W \to p(W)$ of the homeomorphism $p_V : V \stackrel{p}{\to} U$ is again a homeomorphism. We claim that $p(W) = U'$. Trivially $p(W) \subset p(p^{-1}(U')) = U'$. But for each $x \in U' \subset U$ we have $p_V^{-1}(x) \in V$ and $p_V^{-1}(x) \subset p^{-1}(U')$, thus $p_V^{-1}(x) \in V \cap p^{-1}(U') = W$ and $p(p_V^{-1}(x)) = x$. Since $p_W$ is a homeomorphism, $W$ is connected. Therefore all but one $W_\alpha$ must be empty. Hence $W = W_{\alpha(y)}$. We therefore get $p_{\alpha(y)}(W_{\alpha(y)}) =p(W) = U'$. Since $p_{\alpha(y)}$ is a homeomorphism, we conclude $W_{\alpha(y)} = V'_{\alpha(y)}$. Hence $y \in V'_{\alpha(y)} = W_{\alpha(y)} \subset V$.